# WatiN and RadAsyncUpload

Tags: watin

I am using WatiN to run some UI automated tests on my application that uses Telerik RadControls.  I have been able to interact with most of telerik controls, except RadAsyncUpload.

Currently I am unable to upload a file using WatiN.  I understand that telerik uses another testing platform, but I am looking to see if maybe someone can help me figure out how to use WatiN to uplad a file via the RadAsynUpload control.

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="upAttachment" runat="server"AllowedFileExtensions=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png,.bmp" TabIndex="9">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the test failure is caused by third party modules like silverlight, flash and file api which RadAsyncUpload uses. Try to set **DisablePlugins="True"**. Note that this can break existing functionality like MultiFileSelection.